# ValueError: Must be all encoded bytes when reading csv with 0 and 1 in pandas

Tags: pandas, types, type-conversion, boolean

I am trying to read a csv with 1s and 0s and convert them to True and False, because I have a lot of columns I would like to use the `true_values` and `flase_values` arguments, but I got
ValueError: Must be all encoded bytes:

```
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv(StringIO("""var1, var2
0,   0
0,   1
1,   1
0,   0
0,   1
1,   0"""), true_values=[1],false_values=[0])
```

I cannot find the problem with the code that I wrote.

Comment: FYI, to use this parameters, you have to pass a list of string (and not integer) like `true_values=['1']` but it does not change the final behavior.

Comment: @Corralien thanks a lot, maybe I will open an issue on pandas because it seems to me quite a strange behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `true_values` and `false_values` parameters. Use `dtype` instead:

```
>>> pd.read_csv(StringIO("""var1,var2
0,0
0,1
1,1
0,0
0,1
1,0"""), dtype={'var1': bool, 'var2': bool})

    var1   var2
0  False  False
1  False   True
2   True   True
3  False  False
4  False   True
5   True  False
```

If your columns have same prefix, use `filter`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""..."""))
cols = df.filter(like='var').columns
df[cols] = df[cols].astype(bool)
```

If your columns are consecutive, use `iloc`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""..."""))
cols = df.iloc[:, 0:2].columns
df[cols] = df[cols].astype(bool)
```

Auto-detection:

```
m = df.min().eq(0) & df.max().eq(1)
df.loc[:, m] = df.loc[:, m].astype(bool)
```

Comment: Thanks but I have a lot of columns to convert, sorry I did not explain it before

Comment: Do your boolean columns have the same prefix or are they consecutive?

Comment: I updated my answer again with another alternative